# finding value corresponding other value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Well for an assignment (I'm a beginner) I have to find the max. temperature and the corresponding date. This is my code but it's not working. I know that I'm defining date wrong or that I should try another approach but I don't know what to do differently. I get the following error: ***TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers [-1.3] of class 'numpy.float64'***

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data
data = pd.read_csv("klimaat.csv")
data["TX"] /= 10
maxvalue = data['TX'][0]

for i in range(1, len(data["TX"])):
    if(data["TX"][i] > maxvalue):
        maxvalue = data["TX"][i]

date = data["DATE"][maxvalue]
print(maxvalue,date)
```

screenshot of my data file:
[csv file!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnVYy.png)

Comment: Can you provide an excerpt of what your data looks like?

Comment: @cer I've edited my post!

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to skin a cat -- this approach is not the most efficient, but here is the concept:

Place your temperatures into one list, and the dates in another. Find the max of temperature and its location within the list. Use the location to find the date that corresponds to the max temperature.

```
temperatures = []
dates = []

with open('filename.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    input_file.readline() #this skips the header
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        sLine = line.split(',')

        date = sLine[2]
        temp = sLine[3]

        temperatures.append(temp)
        dates.append(date)


maxtemp = max(temperatures)
location = temperatures.index(maxtemp)

print(max(temperatures))
print(location)
print(dates[location])
```

Comment: So are you saying I shouldn't continue with what I have?

Comment: As cer said, this method works, but it is far from optimal.  I recommend continuing with the Pandas solution you have in place.  Learning to use Pandas will be more beneficial than learning to loop through lists.  Don't misunderstand, cer's answer is useful, but from a data analysis perspective learning how to operate in Pandas will be of more benefit.

Comment: I get it, I'm going to try cer's method :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using your temperature as the index value in this line:

```
date = data["DATE"][maxvalue]
```

maxvalue is a temperature and you are using it as an index.  You can get the index value (i.e. the date) via:

```
date = data.DATE[data.TX==maxvalue]
```

NOTE: if using floats, be careful in comparing the float values.

Comment: When I do that, I get this output; 36.8 Int64Index([16978], dtype='int64')

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the dataframe index was a datetime.  I updated my answer.

Comment: After  updating my answer I see that your original solution was not that far off!  A minor error so take joy in knowing you were VERY close.

Comment: Now I get this: "36.8 16978    19470627
Name: DATE, dtype: int64" The date is there (19470627) but all these other things I don't need...

Comment: This makes sense since you are assigning the value at data["TX"][i] to "maxvalue".  When doing data.DATE[data.TX==maxvalue] you are SLICING the dataframe (i.e. limiting the dataframe to only contain rows where data.TX==maxvalue) and are not getting the value.  You need to play around with your code to understand what is happening (try running in IPython or Spyder etc.).  You can get the values from your sliced dataframe via date.get_values()[0] as a start.